# adding additional network adapter to use host only network with dhcp in vagrant using virtualbox provider

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

here's what I am trying to achieve

1. adapter 1 runs on usual NAT
2. add an additional adapter using the vboxnet0 host only network I have created in virtual box, this one uses DHCP server

the reason I need dhcp server is because there is a logstash server running on vagrant box in the same host machine and all the other boxes that I bring up using vagrant should be shipping to this logstash instance, and hence I have to use the hostname `logstash.agilityroots.com` in each of them instead of relying on hardcoding IPs to each of them.

the Host only network and dhcp settings are on Virtualbox as follows

```
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:bin anadi$ VBoxManage list -l hostonlyifs
Name:            vboxnet0
GUID:            786f6276-656e-4074-8000-0a0027000000
DHCP:            Disabled
IPAddress:       192.168.10.1
NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
IPV6Address:     
IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
MediumType:      Ethernet
Status:          Up
VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0


Anadis-MacBook-Pro:bin anadi$ VBoxManage list -l dhcpservers
NetworkName:    HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0
IP:             192.168.56.100
NetworkMask:    255.255.255.0
lowerIPAddress: 192.168.56.101
upperIPAddress: 192.168.56.254
Enabled:        Yes
```

here's the vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.define "full-stack-env" do |dev|
      dev.vm.box = "devops-vm"
      dev.vm.hostname = "full-stack-env.agilityroots.com"

      dev.vm.synced_folder "../../shared-data/yum", "/yum"
      dev.vm.synced_folder "../../puppet-manifests/files", "/etc/puppet/files"

      # add additional adapter for inter machine networking
      dev.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
      #dev.vm.network :private_network, :type => "dhcp", :adapter => "2"

      dev.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22,host: 4223, id: "ssh", auto_correct: true
      #setting port forward for tomcat
      dev.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8090
      #setting port forward for elasticsearch
      dev.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9200, host: 9200

      dev.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vbox|
        vbox.name = "full-stack-env"
      end

      dev.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
        puppet.options = "--verbose --fileserverconfig=/vagrant/fileserver.conf"
        puppet.module_path = "../../puppet-manifests/modules"
        puppet.manifests_path = "../../puppet-manifests/dev-env"
        puppet.manifest_file = "site.pp"
      end
  end
end
```

this throws the error

```
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:full-stack-env anadi$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'full-stack-env' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* An IP is required for a private network.
```

is there a way to get vagrant using DHCP enabled host only networking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should have been fixed in Vagrant 1.5.2 ([issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3267)). So you could either upgrade or use a symbol:

```
dev.vm.network "private_network", type: :dhcp
```

Comment: got that bit to work but a new problem now, http://serverfault.com/questions/601664/vagrant-fails-to-bring-up-additional-adapter-for-centos-vm-using-virtual-box-pro