# vagrant fails to bring up additional adapter for centos vm using virtual box provider

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, centos6.5, nic

this is in continuation of the question [asked here about host only adapter on dhcp](https://serverfault.com/questions/601517/adding-additional-network-adapter-to-use-host-only-network-with-dhcp-in-vagrant)

I upgraded to vagrant 1.6.3 and the updated Vagrantfile to following setting for multiple adapters

```
# add additional adapter for inter machine networking
dev.vm.network :private_network, :type => "dhcp", :adapter => "2", :netmask => "255.255.255.0"
```

it goes through creating adapters but then fails bringing up the mic on vm

```
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:full-stack-env anadi$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'full-stack-env' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> full-stack-env: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> full-stack-env: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> full-stack-env: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    full-stack-env: Adapter 1: nat
    full-stack-env: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> full-stack-env: Forwarding ports...
    full-stack-env: 22 => 4223 (adapter 1)
    full-stack-env: 8080 => 8090 (adapter 1)
==> full-stack-env: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> full-stack-env: Booting VM...
==> full-stack-env: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    full-stack-env: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:4223
    full-stack-env: SSH username: vagrant
    full-stack-env: SSH auth method: private key
    full-stack-env: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    full-stack-env: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    full-stack-env: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> full-stack-env: Machine booted and ready!
==> full-stack-env: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> full-stack-env: Setting hostname...
==> full-stack-env: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

ARPCHECK=no /sbin/ifup eth 2> /dev/null

Stdout from the command:

Device eth does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.


Stderr from the command:
```

how ever when I log in to the environment I see two network interfaces as expected

```
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:full-stack-env anadi$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Wed Jun  4 12:54:47 2014 from 10.0.2.2
[vagrant@full-stack-env ~]$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:BD:39:57  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:febd:3957/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:511 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:360 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:54574 (53.2 KiB)  TX bytes:46675 (45.5 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:A3:86:C9  
          inet addr:172.28.128.3  Bcast:172.28.128.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fea3:86c9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1360 (1.3 KiB)  TX bytes:894 (894.0 b)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

I am bit confused here on why it is trying to add another mic (eth2)? In the VM I used for creating this vagrant box, I had added two NICs already.

Comment: Have you tried without the `:adapter` and `:netmask` options? Those should be automatic.

Comment: that worked! dev.vm.network :private_network, :type => "dhcp"